# Controlling DC Motor with stepper driver

Tags: motor, dc, stepper-driver

I only have a stepper motor driver TB6600 available at the moment, can I use it for control of a a brushed dc motor? I think it should work as I could use PWM. I also want to be able to reverse direction. I looked through the datasheets and online tutorials but I could not find out how to connect the pins and what mode to select.

My question: Is it possible to control a dc brushed motor with TB6600, and if yes, how?

Comment: Where's the link to the datasheet for the TB6600? There's an edit link below your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brushed motor requires a DC voltage to reach full speed and start with full torque then uses it’s armature to self commutate which also results in large BEMF energy released during commutation with only 2 wires to input mux’d to each coil.

A stepper driver always gives 50% duty cycle output as it commutates 1 of 4 phases or full steps to 2 coils and only gives DC when stopped.

Therefore it is incompatible to control velocity with a position control stepper driver.